# media sideload image and Google Content

Tags: images, uploads, google

I'm trying to take a pages og:image from a URL and add it to the media library and post meta. Works great until I hit a google user content url.

```
$image_url = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ApY_G9QDLuhi5pUrrHnUma72_MnSjP6ZN-N6qqRIpWARO-67CmGWsYB9vrTyIEbqm2SUcQ=w1200-h630-p"

media_sideload_image( $image_url, $post_id, '', 'src' );
```

Results in "not valid image url". I would guess it has to do with how the google image url for og:image doesn't have any type of image extension on it. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little searching and it looks like *maybe* you can fix it by appending `?.jpg` to the end of the URL.  According to [this guide](https://www.rainsberger.ca/2016/02/19/direct-link-to-image-in-google-photos-for-html-image-tag/) that gets around most URL parsers

Comment: Didn't quite work, but after some digging based on that answer I did find the solution. Thanks! https://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/Home/Picasa-FAQ/google-photos-1/how-to/how-to-get-a-direct-link-to-an-image